# How do I tell that $f(x)= x \sin(x)$ is an even function?

Tags: integration, functions

> $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi /2} x \sin x \, dx = 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} x \sin x \, dx$$

The above is the property of a definite integral with an even function

How do I evaluate or know that the function is even?

I was taught to evaluate $f(-x) = -x \, \sin(-x)$, what does this tell me?

I also know that a sin function is an odd function and shouldn't an odd function multiplied by any function still gives an odd function? an odd function is $f(-x) = - f(x)$

Comment: $\sin (-x)=-\sin x$

Comment: Actually, the product of two odd functions is always an *even* function—verifying this is a good exercise from the definitions! (The sum of two odd functions is alwaysa an odd function—perhaps that's what you were thinking.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"shouldn't an odd function multiplied by any function still gives an odd function?"

No.  Why should it?

.....

If $f(x)$ is odd and $g(x)$ is any function then $g(-x)f(-x)= -g(-x)f(x)$ but as we don't know anything about what $g(-x)$ is compared to $g(x)$ we know nothing.

But note further.  If $g(x)$ is an odd function and $f(x)$ is an odd function then
$g(-x)f(-x) = [-g(x)][-f(x)] = g(x)f(x)]$.  So an odd function multiplied by an odd function is an *even* function(!).

And we are done.  $i(x) = x$ is an odd function (because $i(-x)=-x = -i(x)$).  And $\sin x$ is an odd function.  So $x\sin x$ is the product of two odd functions so it must be even.

.....

And really, we could have just checked it from the beginning.

$(-x)\sin (-x)= (-x)(-\sin x) = (-1)(-1) x\sin x = x\sin x$.

That was all we had to do.

.....

BTW.  An even function times an odd function is odd.  If $g(x)$ is even and $f(x)$ is odd then $g(-x)f(-x) =g(x)(-f(x)) = -g(x)f(x)$.

And an even function times and even function is even.  If $g(x)$ is even and $f(x)$ is even then $g(-x)f(-x) =g(x)f(x)$.

Notice multiplying odd/even functions is analogous to *adding* odd/even numbers.

.....

Research question for you:  How does *composing* odd and even functions behave?

Comment: if evaluating $f(-x)$ and it gives back the same function, doesn't that mean it is an odd function ? or is it an even function?

Comment: It's a definite issue with the odd/even nomenclature. For natural numbers, of course odd times odd is odd. For functions, odd times odd is even. It's better to know the definitions and be able to apply them than it is to remember these kinds of rules.

Comment: "if evaluating f(−x) and it gives back the same function"  I don't know what you mean but "evaluating" or "give back" or "the same function", so I don't know how to answer your question.....  If $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for all $x$ then the function is odd.  And if $f(-x) =f(x)$ then the function is even.  That is all there is to it.  Must functions are neither.

Comment: Case 1:  If $f(-x)=f(x)$ and $g(-x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ then $f(-x)g(-x)=f(x)g(x)$.  So product of even is even.  Case 2:  If $f(-x)=-f(x)$ and $g(-x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ then $f(-x)g(-x) = -f(x)g(x)$.  So odd times even is odd.  Case 3: If $f(-x)=-f(x)$ and $g(-x)=-g(x)$ for all $x$ then $f(-x)g(-x) =(-f(x))(-g(x)) = -(-f(x)g(x))) = f(x)g(x)$ and the product of two odd functions is even.  .... just remember Odd means $f(-x) =-f(x)$  and even means $f(-x)=f(x)$.  Everything else follows directly.

Comment: But forget definitions.  If $f(x) = x\sin x$ then $f(-x) = (-x)\sin (-x)= (-x)(-\sin x) = x\sin x = f(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Given $f(x) = x \, \sin(x)$ then $f(-x)$ can be determined by using $\sin(-x) = - \sin(x)$ and $(-x) = - (x)$, which gives $f(-x) = x \, \sin(x) = f(x)$.
Note that for $\sin(-x)$ the value can be seen by use of
$$ \sin(-x) = \frac{1}{2 i} \, \left( e^{i (-x)} - e^{- i (-x)} \right) =  - \frac{1}{2 i} \, \left( e^{i x} - e^{- i x} \right) = - \sin(x). $$

The integral in question takes the form
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{-a}^{a} f(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_{-a}^{0} f(x) \, dx + \int_{0}^{a} f(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{a} f(-t) \, dt + \int_{0}^{a} f(x) \, dx \hspace{5mm} \text{where} \,  x= -t \, \text{in the first integral} \\
&= \int_{0}^{a} f(x) \, dx + \int_{0}^{a} f(x) \, dx \\
&= 2 \, \int_{0}^{a} f(x) \, dx \\
&= 2 \, \left( \left[- x \, \cos(x) \right]_{0}^{a} + \int_{0}^{a} \cos(x) \, dx \right) \\
&= 2 \, \left( \sin(a) - a \, \cos(a) \right).
\end{align}
If $ a = \frac{\pi}{2}$ then
$$ \int_{- \pi/2}^{\pi/2} f(x) \, dx = 2, $$
where $f(x) = x \, \sin x. $